# Angular Material Flex Layout - center aligning menu buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

How can buttons be center aligned in a material Toolbar?

I've created an Angular Material Toolbar with a **left aligned** title and some **right aligned** links using `<span fxFlex></span>` example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/free-vote-angular-material-starter)

That works great, however, I can't change the links to buttons and **center** those (after removing title)

Problem demonstrated here: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/free-vote-angular-material-menu)

Buttons default to 100% width and I've overridden that to fixed width, but still any attempt to justify-content or use margin:auto with set width fails.

Update: the issue arises when **mat-menu** is added: See what happens when mat-menu is uncommented in app.component.html in [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/free-vote-angular-material-menu-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution would be considered a **workaround** since Material Design has clear guidelines on how everything should look and behave, these guidelines are of course implemented as well in Angular Material, thus any change you want to make to the *looks* and *default behavior* of the components in Angular Material are not exactly *recommended*, but if the changes made benefit your use case and don't break anything, I'd say go ahead with them.

Basically I just targeted `.mat-menu-item` and set the appropriate styles:

```
.mat-menu-item {
  width: unset;
  height: unset;
  line-height: unset;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/free-vote-angular-material-menu-stackoverflow-218rt2

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you try to get ?

Html :

```
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <button mat-menu-item>home</button>
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="tags" #tagsTrigger="matMenuTrigger" (mouseenter)="tagsTrigger.openMenu()">tags</button>
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="points">points</button>
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="profile">profile</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>sign out</button>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
```

Css :

```
.spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jean-baptiste, centering works that way (or using fxFlex) so long as there are no sub-menus.

I've updated my example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/free-vote-angular-material-menu-stackoverflow

Centering is lost when you uncomment the mat-menu.

Any ideas how ot get round that?

Comment: Try targeting `.mat-menu-item` and set your styles on that class

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that works, so long as we don't attempt to use the menu with [matMenuTriggerFor] - the button trigger disappears.

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/free-vote-angular-material-menu-stackoverflow-sub-menu

Comment: My mistake - corrected

Do you consider this solution to be a workaround, or is this documented anywhere?

Comment: This would be a workaround, Angular Material has clear guidelines when it comes to its components, and those are based on Material Design of course, so when you want to change the usual looks and behaviors of a component, it will almost always be a *workaround*, although if it works for your use case, go ahead

Comment: @AlexCooper will you stick with the comment or would you prefer me to put this as an aswer?